Do Git tags have a timestamp indepedent of the commit?
When you tag a commit, I know that you'll have the committer/author timestamp of the commit as well as a ctime/mtime/atime timestamp on the object file, but is there a separate recorded timestamp of when the tag was created/modified?
For example, when we tag a release, can we see the timestamp that the tag was added, or just the timestamps associated with the commit that the tag was added to?

What did you discover by experimenting?

It's your choice. Annotated tags are part of the tracked history and have dates.

Annotated tag has a “tagger” (author) which has a time. The tag is created separately and after the commit. So the time is different.

The reflog also has a timestamp. Every tag creation will get a timesteamp if core.logAllRefUpdates is always. Both lightweight and annotated.

↑ “Every tag creation will get a timesteamp”—and (to clarify) every update to a tag.

It depends.
There are two kinds of tags:

annotated tags
simple tags

Only annotated tags have a separate timestamp. They also have a tag message and record who made the tag ("tagger").
Annotated tags are created with
git tag -a -m "Release v1.0.1." v1.0.1

(If you do not give a tag message with -m, an editor will open where you can supply the message.)
Annotated tags point to a tag object that points to the tagged object, usually a commit (HEAD by default).
Simple tags are created with
git tag v1.0.1

These are simple refs that point to the commit directly without and intermediate tag object.
Both kinds of tags live in the refs/tags hierarchy.

[pedant mode ON] annotated tags are the final object type, (blobs, trees and commits are the others); Git automatically makes references for annotated tags so you wind up with a local refs/tags/ ref to your annotated tags just like you have local refs/heads/ refs to your branches, and whatever other arbitrarily-refs/-prefixed refs you or Git find useful in your work.

“If you do not have an -m, an editor will be provided for you…” tag’n order

Good points. So, simple tags are just references in ref/tags/, with no constitution of their own, and annotated tags are actual objects (where the references actually point to them).

@DustinOprea Or: lightweight tags point directly to commits. Annotated tags point to tag objects and a tag object points to a commit. Either way they are references under refs/tags/*.

having got on the pedant horse I guess I'm riding it, sigh: annotated tags, like refs, can point to any object type. including annotated tags.


is there a separate recorded timestamp of when the tag was created/modified?

Yes, tags are recorded with their own timestamp, which is different from the timestamp of the commit they point to.

can we see the timestamp that the tag was added, or just the timestamps associated with the commit that the tag was added to?

Yes, you can check the timestamp of your annotated tags with git cat-file. The command prints an output in the following form with the -p option, where 1728455816 is the timestamp and +0200 is the timezone offset:
$ git cat-file -p <your_tag>

object ee95f66dd0ab82bbb886b589967ae6698eb2206f
type commit
tag v1.0.0
tagger John Doe <john.doe@mail.com> 1728455816 +0200

tag message

If you prefer to print a tag's timestamp in the form of your locale, you can extract the timestamp from the tagger line, and then use the date bash command.
$ git cat-file -p <your_tag> | egrep '^tagger' | cut -f2 -d '>' | date +%c

Wed Oct  9 08:36:56 2024

